# Is it possible for my player to play 30 first seconds of my audio/video file?

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

Is it possible to make audio player to play a file only 30 first seconds of the file?

Here is just a sample of my player with source of the music (later I'll change so it will be pulled from the database).

```
<div class="col-md-4 player">
  <div class="audio-player">
    <audio id="audio-player"  controls="controls">
      <source src="media/Blue Browne.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
      <source src="media/Blue Browne.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
      <source src="media/Georgia.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
      <source src="media/Georgia.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
    </audio>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
        audioVolume: 'horizontal',
        iPadUseNativeControls: true,
        iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
        AndroidUseNativeControls: true
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Start a counter when the user presses play, when the counter reaches the limit you set, then programatically stop the player. This is a less than ideal solution though. Just put 30 second audio files on your site instead and you're done.

Comment: Darren, i understand but am trying to create a site where i sell these audio/video files, i think it will be much of the load to have the full length files with those of 30 seconds for preview

Comment: Have you tried using a setTimeout function to pause the media when it hits the timeout?

Comment: @silvabizhub I have a site where I sell music - there are programs out there that will go through a directory of audio files and create 30 second samples for you - then just upload them - I did it with Sound Forge

Comment: Darren that looks like an option, i was trying to avoid all those hustles of converting and linking again as i want to store the links in the database for playpreview and for the purchase session

Comment: @MatthewBeaudin how do i set that ? it could be a relief and honestly am not good on javascript, I want either to stop or to go to the following song according to their row in the database

Comment: @silvabizhub https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976812/6928655

Comment: Darren Sweeney on your site do you count how many times a song has played ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if these event names are correct but this underlying code should work.

```
var playTimeout;    

$("#audio-player").on("play", function(e) {
    playTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("audio-player").pause();
        $("audio-player").setCurrentTime(0); // Restarts video
    }, 30000); // 30 seconds in ms
});


$("#audio-player").on("pause", function(e) {
    clearTimeout(playTimeout);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew Beaudin

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler for the timeupdate event. It will be called every second or so at regular intervals. Within the event handler function you can check the current player duration. If it is 30 seconds or more, you can stop the player. It will ensure that your video does not play for more than 30 seconds.

Have a look at the MediaElement documentation: https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md#events